# References in code moved from Activity to Fragment no longer resolve

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new working with Android/Java, so please bear with me.

I moved code from `LoginActivity > onCreate` into a fragment I created `FragmentLogin` to method `onCreate` where many classes no longer resolve, such as `findViewById`. I'm assuming that somewhere I didn't pass the context of the container Activity properly.

Or some other newbie mistake...

Here is LoginActivity.java [relevant parts copied]

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize Fragments //
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);
    }
}
```

and FragmentLogin.java:

```
public class FragmentLogin extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

        final ValidationManager Check = new ValidationManager();
        final SessionManager Session = new SessionManager(this);

        final EditText textEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        final EditText textPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_pass);
        final Button buttonLogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        final Button buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_signup);

        // Listen for FORGOTTEN PASSWORD click event, open ForgottenPassword Fragment //
        final Button forgottenPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_lost_pass);
        forgottenPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.fragment_forgotten_password);
            }
        });

    ... more code ...

    }
}
```

The variables/methods that were working when the second block of code was residing in the `onCreate` method of the Activity but no longer resolve after I moved the code to `onCreateView` of the `FragmentLogin` fragment class:

`findViewById`, `setContentView`

Basically, this is a login form where the default fragment should be `login`, and a button on that page (`Button forgottenPassword`) would open another fragment (`FragmentForgottenPassword`).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your fragment transaction is not commited, you have to do ```beginTransaction().add/replace/.commit()```, also move the ```setContentView``` after ```super.onCreate```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your activity layout xml file, add something similar to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="your.package.FragmentLogin"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_login"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your LoginActivity: remove the fragment manager stuff. You don't need it yet.

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);
    }
}
```

In your FragmentLogin, move the return statement to the end and use the inflated view to find your views by id:

```
public class FragmentLogin extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final view view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

        final ValidationManager Check = new ValidationManager();
        final SessionManager Session = new SessionManager(this);

        final EditText textEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        final EditText textPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.login_pass);
        final Button buttonLogIn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        final Button buttonSignup = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_signup);

        // Listen for FORGOTTEN PASSWORD click event, open ForgottenPassword Fragment //
        final Button forgottenPassword = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_lost_pass);
        forgottenPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.fragment_forgotten_password);
            }
        });

    ... more code ...

        return view;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this helped immensely.

Answer (score 0):

You should get subviews from layout while it's being inflated. The layout usually inflated in `OnCreateView` method.

```
View layout = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_login, null );

final EditText textEmail = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.login_email);
final EditText textPassword = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.login_pass);

...

return layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to the fragment to be shown within the activity. Try this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //put the setContentView() before the fragment initialization also, I noticed your activity layout is the same as your fragment layout,this should not be so, hence I changed that
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        // Initialize Fragments //
        //you did not initialize the fragments completely, it should be like
       //this
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentLogin()).commit();


    }}
```

then in the Login fragment, it should be like this:

```
 public class FragmentLogin extends Fragment {@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    final ValidationManager Check = new ValidationManager();
    final SessionManager Session = new SessionManager(this);

    final EditText textEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    final EditText textPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.login_pass);
    final Button buttonLogIn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
    final Button buttonSignup = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_signup);

    // Listen for FORGOTTEN PASSWORD click event, open ForgottenPassword Fragment //
    final Button forgottenPassword = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_lost_pass);
    forgottenPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //you cant call setContentView in a fragment

        }
    });

... more code ...

}}
```

I am not totally sure I caught all your mistakes but I think you should read these: [one](https://www.raywenderlich.com/117838/introduction-to-android-fragments-tutorial) and [two](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html); they are online tutorials on fragments, you can also browse for more. I think it is a good starting point. All the best